# I need to run a script that will return to me any sAMAccountname in AD that is in uppercase initial letter

Tags: powershell, uppercase

I found below command which return all sAMAccountname in AD that has all uppercase letter. I am looking for a command that will return to me any sAMAccountname in AD that is in uppercase initial letter.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | ? {$_.sAMAccountname -ceq $_.sAMAccountname.ToUpper()}
```

The intent is to identify all AD user accounts that have an uppercase initial letter in their `SamAccountName` property; e.g., `Abcd` (initial `A` letter is in uppercase) so that later we can convert them to all-lowercase.

Comment: Why does it need to be converted to lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **limit your test to the *first character* of the account name**:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |
  Where-Object { $_.sAMAccountname[0] -ceq [char]::ToUpper($_.sAMAccountname[0]) }
```

---

A **more readable alternative** suggested by [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) is to use the `-clike` operator with a wildcard pattern:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -clike '[A-Z]*' }
```

*Caveat*: This **limits matching to ASCII-range letters `A` through `Z`** and won't detect foreign uppercase characters such as `Ö`.

Comment: Thanks, @AnsgarWiechers - I've added your suggestion to the answer, along with a note that this approach limits you to matching ASCII letters only.

Comment: @mklement0 : The first command only shows for service accounts. The below command which you sent is actually fulfilled my requirement . Thanks mklement0  and Ansgar Wiechers . Really appreciate your help.  
 Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -clike '[A-Z]*' }

Comment: @SunilPoddar: Glad to hear that Ansgar's command worked for you, but (for ASCII-range letters) the 1st command should work the same. Can you give an example name where it doesn't work? Here's a simple test to show that it works with `.SamAccountName` properties that are _strings_ - which, as far as I know, is true of user objects output by `Get-ADUser`: `[pscustomobject] @{ samaccountname = 'Alex' }, [pscustomobject] @{ samaccountname = 'alex' }  | ? { $_.sAMAccountname[0] -ceq [char]::ToUpper($_.sAMAccountname[0]) }`